# How to detect touch event across multiple views on my view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

In my viewController I have programmatically created several squares as sub-views.
Imagine it as a chessboard.

I would like to implement a method that executes some actions upon the sub-view (e.g., change the background color of a single square) when it gets touched by the user.

I have unsuccessfully tried with the UITapGestureRecognizer - I have read from Apple documentation that it applies only to one view at a time.

Do you have any suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a collection view for that chess-like ground?

Comment: You are right - Probably the most easy solution here. Playing with subviews is a bit of a mess indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
class YourCustomView : UIView {

    func  addTapGesture(action : @escaping ()->Void ){
        self.gestureRecognizers?.forEach({ (gr) in
            self.removeGestureRecognizer(gr)
        })
        let tap = MyTapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        tap.action = action
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }
}
```

or you can use this even in a extension of UIView if you're going to use it in multiple types of UIViews.

And then use it like:

```
let yourView = YourCustomView()
yourView.addTapGesture{[weak self] in
    //implement tap event here
}
```

Notice that [weak self] is going to avoid getting a strong reference for closure to avoid a retain cycle there.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this and despite I create a function "handleTap" it's not seen as in scope. I suppose because it's in a closure?

Comment: Yeah. Closures have their own individual namespace. If your handleTap is in where you define the method and closure, you can access it using optional self (self?.handleTap)

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass UIWindow class and handle all the events in `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` there like sending notifications to all the views or communicate with some other way. Check the following repository for more info:
https://github.com/mwinoto/TapDetectingWindow